# Determine if a URL is a link to a mp4 video in Android app?

Tags: android

I have an app that is displaying a webpage using a WebView control.  I can't get MP4 videos to play from within the WebView control and so I have to go a different route.

I am overriding the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method WebViewClient so that I can determine if the URL is an mp4 video link.  If it is, I want to send the link to the android internal video player, otherwise, let it go on.

I could parse the string but I want to use the Uri class.  I'm new to URL's and don't understand the format (components) of a URL.  How can I determine if the following URL:

```
http://www.mobilityinitiative-test.com/images/stories/videos/Introduction.mp4
and
http://www.mobilityinitiative-test.com/images/stories/videos/Synergy.mp4
```

are in fact links to mp4 videos?

Once determined, what's the best way to launch the internal video player?  I've seen several ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` function in your custom `WebChromeClient()`.

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            //handle all audio and video links to mp3, mp4 and 3gp files
            if (url.contains(".mp3"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            else if (url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".3gp"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after the mimetype of the document you're opening (video/mp4).

I'd post an example code, but there's already multiple examples available here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

I would recommend starting with the example based on java.net.URL (the second example).